# Mongodb data sync between primary and secondary node even when port is closed

Tags: mongodb, aws

I have configured mongodb replicaset in aws using 3 ec2's with one primary and 2 secondary nodes. When I insert data on primary node it is getting synced to the secondary nodes which it should. But when I close the port via security group still the data is syncing to the secondary node whose port is closed even though the state in rs.status() in the primary node is stateStr" : "(not reachable/healthy)" -> for the secondary node(whose port is closed).

I tried this with my secondary node in different subnet public as well as private but its still getting synced.I am new to mongodb and might be doing something wrong. Could someone please suggest something.

Comment: ,which version of MongoDB, you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Have you closed that path both ways...

If primary cannot "ping" secondary, it's not reachable/healthy, but if secondary can connect primary, it can replicate opLog...

Answer (score 0):

As per MongoDB BOL [Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-sync/)

In order to maintain up-to-date copies of the shared data set, secondary members of a replica set `sync` or replicate data from other members. MongoDB uses two forms of data synchronization:

1. Initial Sync
2. Replication

**Initial Sync**

Initial sync copies all the data from one member of the replica set to another member.
Even the  initial sync to populate new members with the full data set, and replication to apply ongoing changes to the entire data set.

**How the Process happened in Sync**

```
When you perform an initial sync, MongoDB:
```

Clones all databases except the `local` database. To clone, the `mongod` scans every collection in each source database and inserts all data into its own copies of these collections.
Changed in version 3.4: Initial sync builds all collection indexes as the documents are copied for each collection. In earlier versions of MongoDB, only the _id indexes are built during this stage.

Changed in version 3.4: Initial sync pulls newly added oplog records during the data copy. Ensure that the target member has enough disk space in the local database to temporarily store these oplog records for the duration of this data copy stage.

Applies all changes to the data set. Using the oplog from the source, the `mongod` updates its data set to reflect the current state of the replica set.
When the initial sync finishes, the member transitions from `STARTUP2` to `SECONDARY`.

**Replication**

Secondary members replicate data continuously after the initial sync. Secondary members copy the `oplog` from their sync from source and apply these operations in an asynchronous process.

Secondaries may automatically change their sync from source as needed based on changes in the ping time and state of other members’ replication.

Changed in version 3.2: MongoDB 3.2 replica set members with `1 vote` cannot sync from members with `0 votes`.

Secondaries avoid syncing from `delayed members` and `hidden members`.

If a secondary member has `members[n].buildIndexes` set to true, it can only sync from other members where `buildIndexes` is true. Members where `buildIndexes` is false can sync from any other member, barring other sync restrictions. `buildIndexes` is true by default.

For Your Further Ref [Replica Set Oplog](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/) and [Replica Set Deployment Architectures](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-architectures/)